# nonexpansiveness of prox-grad mapping

Tags: operator-theory, fixed-point-theorems

Let $f,g$ be two convex functions and $g$ has Lipchitz continuous gradient. The proximal - gradient mapping, which defined as
$$ x \mapsto \textrm{prox}_{\lambda f} \left( x - \lambda \nabla g \left( x \right) \right) . $$

> How can I prove that the proximal - gradient mapping is nonexpansive?

I only able to prove it when $g \equiv 0$. In particular, for any
$$ x^{+} = \textrm{prox}_{\lambda f} \left( x - \lambda \nabla g \left( x \right) \right) \textrm{ and } y^{+} = \textrm{prox}_{\lambda f} \left( y - \lambda \nabla g \left( y \right) \right) $$
we have that
$$ x - \lambda \nabla g \left( x \right) - x^{+} \in \lambda \partial f \left( x^{+} \right) \textrm{ and } y - \lambda \nabla g \left( y \right) - y^{+} \in \lambda \partial f \left( y^{+} \right) $$
which, by the monotonicity of $\partial f$ implies further
$$ \left\langle  x - \lambda \nabla g \left( x \right) - x^{+} - \left( y - \lambda \nabla g \left( y \right) - y^{+} \right) , x^{+} - y^{+} \right\rangle \geq 0 $$
or equivalently
$$ \left\langle  x - y - \lambda \left( \nabla g \left( x \right) - \nabla g \left( y \right) \right) , x^{+} - y^{+} \right\rangle \geq \left\lVert x^{+} - y^{+} \right\Vert ^{2} . $$
Infact, when $g \equiv 0$ we have that
$$ \left\langle  x - y , x^{+} - y^{+} \right\rangle \geq \left\lVert x^{+} - y^{+} \right\Vert ^{2} $$
which means the $\textrm{prox}$ mapping is not only nonexpansive but also *firmly nonexpansive*. However, the appearance of $g$ make me confuse. I tried to use the Cauchy - Schwarz inequality then Lipchitz continuity of $\nabla g$ but it leads to some constant bigger than $1$:
\begin{align*}
\left\lVert x^{+} - y^{+} \right\Vert ^{2} & \leq \left\langle  x - y , x^{+} - y^{+} \right\rangle - \lambda \left\langle \nabla g \left( x \right) - \nabla g \left( y \right) , x^{+} - y^{+} \right\rangle \\
& \leq \left\lVert x - y \right\Vert \left\lVert x^{+} - y^{+} \right\Vert + \lambda \left\lVert\nabla g \left( x \right) - \nabla g \left( y \right) \right\Vert \left\lVert x^{+} - y^{+} \right\Vert \\
& \leq \left( 1 + \lambda L \right) \left\lVert x - y \right\Vert \left\lVert x^{+} - y^{+} \right\Vert .
\end{align*}
Can anyone tell me where did I miss?

Comment: The shortest (but not easiest) way of proving this is to use operator theory (like your tag suggests). Basically, the prox operator is equivalent to applying $(I+t\partial f)^{-1}$ on $x$, where $\partial f$ is the subdifferential of $f$. Then $x^+ = (I+t\partial f)^{-1}(I-t\nabla g)x$. It can be shown that $(I-t\nabla g)$ contracts by factor $tL$ where $L$ is the Lipshitz constant of $\nabla g$ (so you pick $t=1/L$), and $ (I+t\partial f)^{-1}$ is nonexpansive. (See the Eckstein / Bertsekas paper for a better proof of that.) Then your proof should be 3 lines.

Comment: correction, it contracts by a factor of $1-tL$, not $tL$.

Comment: @whyyes can you please give me a hint on proving $\left( I - t \nabla g \right)$ is contracts by a factor of $1 - tL$? I can only prove it nonexpasive, otherwise I have to assume $g$ to be strongly convex

Comment: yeah. I just doubled checked my "proof" and realized it was incorrect. I'll think on this some more...

Comment: but I think that $\left( I - t \nabla g \right) ^{-1}$ is nonexpansive is still enough as $\left( I + t \partial f \right)$ is nonexpansive as well, therefore the composition is also nonexpansive :)
but it would be very interesting if we can check that whether $\left( I - t \nabla g \right) ^{-1}$ is contraction or not without strongly convexity assumption ^^

Comment: Yeah so the stuff you added was exactly what I was thinking, and the mistake was exactly what you pointed out: it's (1+tL) not (1-tL). This is the nicest proof I can find, I think it's the same one in Nesterov's introductory lectures: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ggordon/10725-F12/slides/05-gd-revisited.pdf

Comment: By the way, here is a nice overall proof for proximal gradient convergence. https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~elghaoui/Teaching/EE227A/lecture18.pdf
Since he introduces nonexpansiveness for prox but not for the prox + gradient, I guess actually, without strong convexity, prox + gradient maybe isn't contractive. (Even for strongly convex, I don't think the proof is obvious... all I've seen (now that I'm looking) is $x^k-x*$, not $x^+-x$...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sketch for when $\nabla g$ is $L$-Lipschitz continuous and $\lambda\in]0,1/L[$. This uses the tools from Bauschke/Combettes' book vol. 2, mostly chapters 4 and 18.

Since $g$ is convex, the Baillon-Haddad theorem implies that $\lambda\nabla g$ is firmly nonexpansive. Therefore, $\textrm{Id} - \lambda\nabla g$ is firmly nonexpansive, hence nonexpansive.

Since $f$ is convex, $\textrm{prox}_{\lambda f}$ is also firmly nonexpansive, hence nonexpansive.

The proximal gradient operator (more generally called the "forward-backward" operator) is nonexpansive since it is the composition of two nonexpansive operators (in fact, it is $2/3$-averaged).